# Execute PHP script daily Cron on my local machine that runs Fedora

Tags: linux, cron, fedora, cron-task

I am aware of the fact this is a usual question for Cron, but I have tried just about everything I have found and nothing seems to work.

I have a php script in: `home/user/path/to/file/script.php`

That connects to an API through its provided library and sends an email of the results it found.

So far, I've tried:

1. putting the script in `etc/cron.daily`
2. `crontab -e` and writing there:

   - `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/path/to/file/script.php`
   - `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/path/to/file/script.php`
   - `00 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/path/to/file/script.php`
   - `*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /home/user/path/to/file/script.php` and others

`crontab -l` indeed shows the most recent cron job I inputted through `crontab -e`, but they haven't, so far, sent out an email or anything. The script executes perfectly when I run it through the terminal.